# Conflicts between different Angular.js versions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, yeoman-generator-angular

I am building a single page webapp with Angular.js. I started out with a scaffolded version of an Angular project build with Yeoman (yeoman/generator-angular) and I added another Angular module to the project. When I am running the latter module as "stand alone", not incorporated into the scaffolded project, it is running fine. As soon as I try to incorporate the module into the scaffolded project, it causes conflicts which seem to be related to different Angular.JS versions needed by the module and the scaffolded project. What would be the best approach when running different Angular.js versions and maintaining upward compatibility? Any hints would be appreciated, Thanks. As the project is already very complex, I cannot paste some code here, because I would have to paste tons of code to illustrate the problem. Therefore, I would appreciate any hints on a general approach to this problem.

Comment: I doubt you can have different version of angular at the same time. A solution might be to run part of your app in an iframe...

Comment: Which versions of Angular are needed for your module and the project?

Comment: In the bower.json file of the scaffoled angular project, "angular": "~1.3.0"; the module that should be integrated runs with 1.2.11

Comment: And if you try running the module using Angular 1.3, are there any errors? If there are, what are they?

Comment: FYI, migrating from 1.2 to 1.3 is not too bad. I have a lot of modules that work on both. Some just needed a couple changes. Nothing time-consuming.